# df.explode() function not working in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, explode

I am facing a weird issue, I have a column name 'window' in a data frame and it has a list of values i.e., [3,9,45,78]. I am trying to explode this column using df.explode('window') but this is doing no job. datatype of 'window' column is object.
I have checked my pandas version it is - 1.3.4

[dataframe example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ0i3.png)

Comment: Do you really have a list of values, or do you have a string that LOOKS like a list of values?

Comment: ColumnAA - [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24] , its datatype is object.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `df.explode` does not do its work in place.  It RETURNS a new dataframe with the changes:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [ 0, [1,2,3], [4,5,6], 7 ],
    [ 0, [1,2,3], [4,5,6], 7 ],
    [ 0, [1,2,3], [4,5,6], 7 ],
    [ 0, [1,2,3], [4,5,6], 7 ],
    [ 0, [1,2,3], [4,5,6], 7 ]
]

df = pd.DataFrame( data, columns=['one', 'two','three','four'] )
print(df)
df2 = df.explode('two')
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   one        two      three  four
0    0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]     7
1    0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]     7
2    0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]     7
3    0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]     7
4    0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]     7
   one two      three  four
0    0   1  [4, 5, 6]     7
0    0   2  [4, 5, 6]     7
0    0   3  [4, 5, 6]     7
1    0   1  [4, 5, 6]     7
1    0   2  [4, 5, 6]     7
1    0   3  [4, 5, 6]     7
2    0   1  [4, 5, 6]     7
2    0   2  [4, 5, 6]     7
2    0   3  [4, 5, 6]     7
3    0   1  [4, 5, 6]     7
3    0   2  [4, 5, 6]     7
3    0   3  [4, 5, 6]     7
4    0   1  [4, 5, 6]     7
4    0   2  [4, 5, 6]     7
4    0   3  [4, 5, 6]     7
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! it was quick.